# How to use C++ dll in python

Tags: python, c++, dll, wrapper

I have a library with functions and structures written in C++. It can also be used in C# using a wrapper in a cs-file, which describes C# interfaces that call functions from a DLL. That is, to use the C# API, you only need a DLL file. How can I do the same for python? In addition to the DLL, I also have the .h file, but not the .cpp file.

Comment: Look at Boost. It may be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) and you have to have an intermediate layer of C.

Let us say we have a file called duck.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class Duck 
{
public: 
    void quack() {std::cout << "Quck\n";}
};

extern "C" {
  Duck* New_Duck(){return new Duck();}
  void Duck_Quack(Duck* duck) {duck->quack();}
}
```

The compiled, here with G++, I will generate an .so and not a dll as I am on Linux:

```
g++ -c -fPICK duck.cpp -o duck.o
g++ -shared -Vl,-soname,libduck.so -o libduck.so duck.o
```

Then in Python

```py
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libduck.so')

class Duck(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.New_Duck()

    def quak(self): 
        lib.quck(self.obj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    duck = Duck()
    duck.quack()
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't generate the .so file because the .cpp file calls for a huge number of other headers needed to compile

Comment: Why not? If it works in C# it should work in Python as well. You will of course need to install dependencies on any deployed system, but that is a requirement for any software

Comment: My situation is more difficult, I literally don't have access to the cpp file. I only have a header and a dll file. And just in the case of working with C#, a file with wrappers is used there that calls functions from the DLL file. I'm looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that... eh then I am not sure it is possible :/